# problem with expo react native navigation

Tags: react-native

i am using react-native with expo to run my app on my android devices when i load my app on my terminal i have this error

Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:

- @react-native-community/masked-view - expected version: 0.1.10 - actual version installed: 0.1.11
  Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
  To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]
  Missing package "metro-config" in the project at: C:\Users\kabore\Desktop\react_native\app1
  This usually means `react-native` is not installed. Please verify that dependencies in package.json include "react-native" and run `yarn` or `npm install`.
  Error: Missing package "metro-config" in the project at: C:\Users\kabore\Desktop\react_nativ

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the node_modules folder and run yarn install or npm install in the command line to install dependencies again .it seems like some of your dependencies are not installed correctly

Comment: when i launch with expo init or yarn init i got this error      throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\kabore\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-native-app\build\index.js'
?[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47?[39m {
  code: ?[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'?[39m,
  requireStack: []
}

Comment: install create-react-native-app with  npm i -g create-react-native-app